# AJAX POST , having problems with "data" field

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I am using auto generated the ajax with Postman 3, so you can tell if it's the correct way to do it, but this isn't my main question. Now, when I  type the "data" field like this, it works

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://baas.kinvey.com/appdata/kid_B1BHxEN7/people/",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "Basic Z2VzaGE6MTIzNA==",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "8de908df-f970-524c-eb8b-d2f7f621a3ac"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\"name\":\"Peter\",\"id\":11}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Now my question is, how do I put custom parameters in the "data" field. 
I want something like this

```
var arr = [{"name": "Peter", "id": 12}, {"name": "Demeter", "id": 15}];

var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://baas.kinvey.com/appdata/kid_B1BHxEN7/people/",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "authorization": "Basic Z2VzaGE6MTIzNA==",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "e37d3063-406d-02c3-803f-0f32666b9d70"
    },
    "processData": false,
    data: {"name": arr[0].name, "id": arr[0].id}
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

When i send this POST request it gives me back **400(Bad request)**

Comment: remove the quotes in your keys like `url` and `method` and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery does not format your request as JSON but only as data url. You have to do this yourself:

```
data: JSON.stringify({"name": arr[0].name, "id": arr[0].id})
```

Comment: It worked, will give you best answer when I'm allowed in a few min. But I just have 1 more question. Why some people write the AJAX keys with quotes, and why some don't? What the difference. I mean "url" or just url

Comment: Because JSON requires the quotes, JavaScript not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string to `JSON` format using `stringify`. Here is link to explanation:

***The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.***

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Thank you, but why some people write the AJAX keys with quotes, and why some don't? What the difference. I mean "url" or just ur

Comment: The quotes do not make a difference, unless you want to use a key that’s not a valid JavaScript identifier.